# I am finding it difficult to understand this question

Tags: combinatorics

Draw a circle $C$ on a plane. Put $n$ points on the circumference of $C$. Join any two of the $n$ points with a chord. Suppose that no three chords intersect at any one point inside $C$. Let $c_n$ be the number of such chords, in that of intersections of the chords inside $C$, and $r_n$ that of the regions in $C$ bounded by an arc and/ or some chords. Find $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5, c_6$ and write their values in this order.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I don't understand it either. "Join any two..." is ambiguous. If they mean "pick two and join them and that's that", then $c_n=1$ but that would be silly. On the other hand, if they want you to join _all pairs_ of points with chords, they should've said so. Plus, they define $r_n$'s but then don't ask anything about them!

Comment: Most people need this question to be displayed on an image in order to understand this. Can you show us the image you made?

Comment: (1) In Case , you have given the Exact wording , then you are rightly confused : nobody (not just you) can make sense out of it ! (2) In Case , you are rewording it (or reporting from memory) then your wording (or your memory) might be wrong !